# ActionBar back button finishing activity from inner Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an AppCompatActivity with an ActionBar incorporating a back button. I am starting a inner Fragment class which opens a View on top of the Activity view. The hardware back button closes the Fragment and the Activity view is visible. If however I press the back button on the ActionBar whilst in the Fragment view, the app goes back to MainActivity, the Activities parent. I want to either hide the ActionBar, or ideally give it the same behaviour as the hardware button, as this is obviously annoying behaviour for the user. I have tried creating an instance of the ActionBar in my Activity, like this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This gives me a `NullPointerException` in runtime. I have searched and am stumped.

Also tried this, where mFragmentManager has .addToBackStack() before it begins the transaction with my Fragment class.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBackPressed. Count = " + count);
}
```

~No errors but the ActionBar back button behaviour is no changed. No Log message is recorded~

My mistake, this method did change behaviour but for the hardware back button. It caused a `NullPointerException` when trying to `getBackStackCount()` on `mFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action bar "back" button is actually the *Up* button, and according to Google it is supposed to behave differently from the hardware back button: https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html

That being said, you can intercept touches on this button and do whatever you want with them.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // your code here
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: 'android.R.id.home' being the top activity in Android Manifest? Or do I need to link to my activity_main.xml? How would I redirect to my activity, by xml layout name or activity name?

Comment: `android.R.id.home` is the id of the home button in the action bar (which will usually have an arrow icon). This is true for all activities and requires no changes to your manifest.

Comment: Ah I see. So in the if method statement I could use an Intent to navigate back to my Activity? That feels like a shame as I expect the data will be reloaded but it's still better than before.

Comment: If all you want to do is pop the fragment off the back stack, you can just insert something like `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); return true;` inside the if statement.

Comment: This assumes that you actually added the fragment transaction to the back stack when you showed the fragment, of course.

Comment: I did, and that has fixed it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead.